# c++ concurrency issue with scaling thread runtime

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have a program that performs the same function on a large array. I break the array into equal chunks and pass them to threads. Currently the threads perform the function and return what they are supposed to, BUT the more threads I add the longer each thread takes to run. Which totally negates the purpose of concurrency. I have tried with `std::thread` and `std::async` both with the same result. In the images below the amount of data processed by all child threads and the main thread are the same size (main has 6 more points), but what main runs in ~ 12 seconds the child threads take ~12 x the number of threads as if they were running asynchronously. But they all start at the same time, and if I output from each thread they are running concurrently. Does this have something to do with how they are being joined? I have tried everything I can think of, any help/advice is much appreciated! In the sample code main doesn't run the function until after child threads finish, if I put the join after the main runs it still doesn't run until the child threads finish. Below you can see the runtimes when run with 3 and 5 threads. These times are on a downscaled dataset for testing.

```
void foo(char* arg1, long arg2, std::promise<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long>>>>>> & ftrV) {
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long>>>>> Grid;

  // does stuff....
  // fills in "Grid"

  ftrV.set_value(Grid);
}


int main(){

  int thnmb = 3;    // # of threads
  std::vector<long> buffers;    // fill in buffers
  std::vector<char*> pointers;  //fill in pointers 

  std::vector<std::promise<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long>>>>>>> PV(thnmb); // vector of promise grids
  std::vector<std::future<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long>>>>>>> FV(thnmb);    // vector of futures grids
  std::vector<std::thread> th(thnmb);   // vector of threads
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long>>>>>> vt1(thnmb);    // vector to store thread grids

  for (int i = 0; i < thnmb; i++) {

    th[i] = std::thread(&foo, pointers[i], buffers[i], std::ref(PV[i]));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < thnmb; i++) {
    FV[i] = PV[i].get_future();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < thnmb; i++) {
    vt1[i] = FV[i].get();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < thnmb; i++) {
    th[i].join();
  }

  // main performs same function as foo here

  // combine data
  // do other stuff..

  return(0);
}
```

[image: run with]

[image: run with 3 threads]

Comment: You should copy and paste the contents of the command window into the question rather than posting a screen shot.

Comment: noted @ 1201ProgramAlarm

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a definitive answer without knowing what `foo` does, but you're probably running into memory access issues.  Each access to your 5 dimension array will require 5 memory lookups, and it only takes 2 or 3 threads with memory access to saturate what a typical system can deliver.

`main` should perform it's `foo` work after creating the threads but before getting the value of the promises.

And `foo` should probably end with `ftrV.set_value(std::move(Grid))` so that a copy of that array won't have to be made.

Comment: Thanks! I believe you are right about the memory access issue. After doing more reading last night I thought it may have something to do with false sharing, but the chunks of the vector that each thread is accessing are separated by 1000's of times longer than my machines cache line so I'm not sure this is the issue. I use a 5 dimensional array because it is is more intuitive to think of my dataset in that way (I know it probably doesn't seem this way), I could break it into a 2D vector with a few changes, would this reduce the memory lookup cost?

Comment: If you can change that to be a flatter 2D vector<vector<something>> type that should help, as it would only need to do 2 memory lookups to access the 2 vectors instead of 5.